# Where is the best place to ask questions about Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Particularly I want to ask: How can a [Google Docs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Docs) document reference a cell in a Google spreadsheet?

Comment: Related: [Where can I ask general questions about a multi-platform app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/373040/289691)

Answer (score 13):

You are looking for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/.

The relevant part of [their topic description page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> If your question generally covers …
>
> - Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which behaves like an application
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: If you look in http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets you might find your question has already been answered.

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in my answer to [Where can I ask general questions about a multi-platform app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/373040/289691),

> It will depend on the specific question (**details are required**) that you want to ask.

Google Sheets is a cross-platform service that might be used by end-users, developers, administrators (Google Workspace), and *citizen developers* (a combo of project managers, solution architects, programmers, integrators, and end-user).

As a spreadsheet *power user* you might want to use Google Sheets on the Web as the apps for Android and iPhone and iPad are very limited compared to what could be done with the app for the Web.

General questions about using Google Sheets on the Web and overall questions might be well suited in [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) if they are properly formulated. I.E. questions about calculations should include sample data showing input and the expected results. You should make use of the proper spreadsheet terminology and describe the problem showing that you understand this app. Otherwise you should support your question by including what you have found in the resources for end-users and why they didn't meet your needs.

Avoid exploratory, discovery questions (is it possible?, how to do x with Google Sheets?) if you don't want to write a well-supported question. Web Applications were flooded with these questions and there isn't a *core community* helping to moderate the site.

Questions about spreadsheet formulas might also be on-topic in Stack Overflow and Super User.

In Stack Overflow there might not be limitations regarding being formulas used on the Web or other platforms. In Super User questions about Google Sheets formulas might be well received apparently while the formulas be compatible with desktop spreadsheet applications like Excel.

Questions about extending Google Sheets i.e. by using macros, or custom functions, might be asked in Web Applications and Stack Overflow.

Questions about creating add-ons for Google Sheets for personal or small group use that don't require advanced programming skills/knowledge and tooling might be asked in Web Applications. The others could be asked in Stack Overflow.

Questions about the iPhone and iPad apps might be asked in Ask Different.

Questions about the Android app might be asked in Android Enthusiasts.

Questions looking for recommendations about Google Sheets add-on, automation tools, and no code / low code platforms that use Google Sheets as a database/data source might be asked in Software Recommendations.

#### [google-sheets] across Stack Exchange sites

Using a question [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/713566/search-for-questions-with-a-specific-tag-across-meta-sites) created by Glorfindel, I retrieved the questions tagged [google-sheets] across the SE sites.

[google-sheets] is the top tag of Web Applications.

| sitename | COUNTA of question |
| --- | --- |
| Stack Overflow | 43420 |
| Web Applications (primarily Web app) | 6469 |
| Stack Overflow em Português | 51 |
| Code Review | 37 |
| Geographic Information Systems | 13 |
| Android Enthusiasts (Only Android app) | 8 |
| Stack Overflow en español | 2 |
| Grand Total | 50000 |

Notes:

- Super User has [[google-spreadsheet]](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets). This tag has +400 questions.
- Ask Different hasn't had a specific tag for Google Sheets questions. Use [google-apps]. The search ["google-sheets"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22google%20sheets%22) returns +50 questions.

### Related

- [Guides to ask a [google-sheets] question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4935/88163)
- [Guide for Google apps users looking for help with features that suddenly stop working](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5000/88163)
- [Should Google Sheets formula questions be asked here or in stackoverflow?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5023/88163)